# PHP web service mini forum query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web, wsdl

i am new to web services kinda thing, and i have a problem that is yet to be solved.

So this is my wsdl

```
<?xml version ='1.0' encoding ='UTF-8' ?>

<definitions name="Biodata"
             targetNamespace="urn:TestNamespace"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:tns="TestNamespace"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
             xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>
<message name='insertReplyRequest'>
                <part name='reply' element="Biodata"/>
            </message>
<portType name='BiodataPortType'>
                <operation name='insertReply'>
                    <input message='tns:insertReplyRequest'>                
                </operation>
</portType>
<binding name='BiodataBinding' type='tns:BiodataPortType'>
                <soap:binding style='rpc' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>
                  <operation name='insertReply'>
                    <soap:operation soapAction='insertReply'/>
                      <input>
                        <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:examples:biodata'
                          encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
                      </input>
                  </operation>
</binding>

<service name='BiodataService'>
                <port name='BiodataPort' binding='tns:BiodataBinding'>
                 <soap:address location='http://localhost/Kevin/FirstWebService/Asynchronous/server.php'/>
                </port>
            </service>  
</definitions>
```

and this is file reply.php

```
    <?php
    $reply = $_POST["reply"];
    $post_id = $_POST["post_id"];
    $client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/Kevin/FirstWebService/Asynchronous/biodata.wsdl");
    $return = $client->insertReply($reply, $post_id);

    header("Location: http://localhost/Kevin/FirstWebService/Asynchronous/reply.html");
    die();
?>
```

reply.html is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reply</title>
</head>

<form action="reply.php" method=POST>
REPLY:<br>
    <input type="text" name="reply">
<br>
POST ID<br>
    <input type="text" name="post_id">
<br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</html>
```

the function is as following:

```
<?php
 function insertReply($reply, $post_id){
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "structure2";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO reply (reply, post_id) VALUES ('$reply', '$post_id')";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

} ?>
```

and the server:

```
<?php
require 'biodata_functions.php';
//require 'SoapFault.php';

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); // disabling WSDL cache
$server = new SoapServer("http://localhost/Kevin/FirstWebService/Asynchronous/biodata.wsdl");
/*$server->addFunction("getName");
*/
$server->addFunction("insertPost");
$server->addFunction("insertReply");
$server->handle();

?>
```

my problem is, i can't insert the $post_id simultaneously with the $reply, and whenever i do, it ends up blank in the sql table.

i have even tries to change the $sql in the functions code to be:
`$sql = "INSERT INTO reply (reply, post_id) VALUES ('$reply', '8')";` and it did inputs 8 successfully in the database.
Is something wrong with my query? or something wrong with my logic? any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: `if($_POST['post_id']){` check if post_id value is present, try printing your query and check whats the value passed to the query

Comment: yes i did, it prints out the value i inputted in the post id box HTML file

Comment: `$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
`